# WSO2 - SAASifying .Net and PHP application

Tags: wso2

I am evaluating WSO2 as potential PAAS platform for delivering multi-tenancy SAAS application to my clients. I know that we can expose JEE based web applications as SAAS applications on WSO2 platform. My question is can we SAASify an application built on .Net or PHP using WSO2 PAAS services. If yes, please let me know what does it take to achieve this. Please point me to any resources if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Via the WSO2 Stratos cartridge architecture, you can easily plug in any runtime as a service - thus you can create a polyglot cartridge for PHP in WSO2 Private PaaS / Stratos to run PHP applications. This will allow you to use the PaaS features such as multi-tenancy and thus work towards SaaSifying your PHP app.

The following [Enterprise Use Case Webinar - Running PHP on Stratos 2.0](http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2013/03/enterprise-use-case-webinar-running-php-stratos/) shows howto create a PHP cartridge and a demo on running PHP based wordpress.